# Relational Database servers auxiliary programming language support

Tags: programming-languages, relational-database

All,
MS sql Server supports CLR languages, Oracle Supports Java,
What are other databases that support such (auxiliary) programming languages..

Just curies ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) has [extensive support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/server-programming.html) for server-side programming using a variety of programming languages.

Comment: I will leave this question un-answered just to attract some more takes.. Upvoted

Comment: I think that Postgres and the commercial DVMS' mentioned are the small club that support Store Procedures with any seriousness. Unless you use an object database like Gemstone where the language of the business objects (Smalltalk or Java and lately Ruby) are the language of the storage objects.